# What is the REST API for HP-ALM to fetch defect history data

Tags: rest, audit, hp-alm, defects

I am fetching data from HP ALM by using REST API. I am able to fetch audit data for tests by using `/qcbin/rest/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/audits?query={parent-type[test];parent-id[101 or 102 or 103]}`. 
But I am not able to fetch the audit data for defect using the same format url. Please let me know what is the rest api to fetch audit data of defect

I have tried to use following url
`/qcbin/rest/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/audits?query={parent-type[defect];parent-id[101 or 102 or 103]}`.

I am getting No enum constant `org.hp.qc.api.entities.AuditLog.AuditAction.CA_Review_Outcome` error while using parent type as defect

Comment: I just tested the URL you suggested and it works fine in our ALM project. So, sorry I have no idea why it does not work on your side. Is it possible to deactivate Audit logs for certain types of entities and is this the case in your project? Maybe check in the UI if defects really have a history if they are created and/or updated.